# Any software to add subtitles to Xvid for playback on a PS3?

Tags: 10.10, video, software-recommendation, ps3

I watch a lot of foreign language films and it really annoys me to not be able to use my PS3 for them without hard coded subs. Is there a piece of software that will let me add the subtitles into the video file (without re-encoding) in a way that will allow the PS3 to recognise them?

Right now I don't have the time to set up a server for media streaming and am ideally looking for something that alters the video file so that it can just be put on a USB drive attached to the PS3. I don't want to have to rely on having another computer running.

Comment: what format does the PS3 use? Maybe you can add them as overlays instead?

Comment: I don't know which format the PS3 accepts for a video file rather than a DVD. When you press the triangle button for options, there is toggle for subtitles, but I've never seen it detect an external subtitle file (usually *.srt?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know only 2 application that can add subtitles to a movie to be viewed by PS3

One, the easiest, is **AVIAddXSubs**.

Sadly is a Windows application but runs under wine.

You can find it here: http://www.calcitapp.com/AVIAddXSubs.php

Tutorial to use with PS3: http://dontcthis.com/2009/09/how-to-add-subtitles-to-your-ps3-movies/

---

The other application is **MEncoder** that is a command line utility for linux.

Sadly, no gui.

How to install: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MEncoder

an sample usage case: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=556267

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at both your suggestions. Would like to use native Linux software if possible.

Comment: That tutorial is gone now.. do you have another one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PS3MediaCenter to directly stream your videos to the PS3 from your computer, 
and you can also stream subtitles.

Blog:
http://ps3mediaserver.blogspot.com/

Project Page:
http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I actually have this software. While I intend to, at some point in the future, set up a server for such a purpose, right now I want a solution that leaves me with a video file that I can chuck onto the USB drive I have connected to my PS3 so that when I want to watch something I don't have to have another computer involved.

Comment: Ok understand, I will post another solution